# How to speed up Wordpress website load time that uses photo slider

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, pagespeed

I have a Wordpress website that has a photo slider on the homepage. I have condensed the size of the images, however the load time is still too slow. Can someone please help me with this? https://bptapartments.com

Answer (score 0):

Is fairly quick for me! However, Imagify is good to compress the images and convert to WebP format. This should make images smaller again based on JPG/PNG formats.

Then look at a decent caching plugin, or a content delivery network for the images on the site. I use WP-Rocket which seems to do really well at increasing image load speed, as well as including lazy-load for images off screen.

Comment: I will try it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Those should do it!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a caching plugin. If you are looking for a free one, then you can try Autoptimize. It really helps to minify the CSS and JS files.

Avoid using too many unnecessary plugins. That makes the site slow.

I ran a speed test and found that your server response time is very high. You should use a better hosting that has a good response time.

Also, use the WebP Express plugin to serve the images in the next-gen format.

I hope that will help to improve the speed.

Comment: This is great, I will definitely try this. Any other ideas?